# net.sf.jni4net; Bridge.CreateJVM(bridgeSetup); Could not reserve enough space for 'X'KB object heap;

Tags: c#, jni4net

I am using net.sf.jni4net in my .Net application.

While calling:

```
Bridge.CreateJVM(bridgeSetup);
```

When the allocated memory is too big, in Debug Ouput I can see the message:

> Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap.

My .Net application crashes. I want to catch that error and write message to my log file with nlog.

How can I achieve that?